# ReactJS Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')

Tags: reactjs, laravel-8

I am working with Laravel8 / ReactJS project and I have a problem. My login form is working fine but when I write correct email and wrong password, I got this error:
[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5qUz.png)

But when I have wrong password or invalid email, I get correct validations from Laravel8 Validator. So maybe someone can help me with this problem. I have been struggling for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here just try optional chaining `loginInputs?.error_list?.email`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Now I know where is a problem. I guess it's with Laravel8, why? Because I think that I didnt make a condition where I check if email is correct but password wrong to return something then Laravel8 return undefined error. This is my guess but I dont know how to solve it

Comment: can you share your code? so that I can look into that properly

Comment: This is Login: ReactJS -> https://pastebin.com/ac91Vx6F

This is Login: Laravel8 -> https://pastebin.com/UVv2SuWb

Comment: error_list is an array so instead of initializing it as an array try to initialize it as an object, i.e, {}

Comment: Can you help me to do that? Because I just entry on this stack of programming

Comment: sure can you provide the code sandbox link so that I can update your code

Comment: If it possible to push respone json message into validation error?

Comment: Instead of push directly assign json object to the validation error

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-dream-c85dds?file=/AuthController.php

Laravel8 sanbox with Login and Register functions

Comment: this is laravel can you provide react code?

Comment: ReactJS -> Login.js: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-dream-5lcmx9?file=/Login.js

Comment: try this code  https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-rgb-zfti3d?file=/Login.js

Comment: Okay ty, but I have a question, you made my error_list as a object yeah? But In laravel8 project it is an array, maybe you know how to make map function to print of all the errors in one place?

Comment: can you share me the array of error_list which you will get from backend?

Comment: Do you mean about preview?: https://ibb.co/80PnQnz